# left-margin shifted table extending outside of parent div

Tags: css

I've placed a table inside a div and set the table width to 100%. I am placing an icon to the left of the table within the div, so I used a `margin-left` property to shift the table over and place the icon using `position:absolute` and `top` and `left` properties. That all works just fine, however the table width is shifted outside of the parent div - apparently because of the `left-margin` setting. Since I need the table to expand dynamically depending on the browser window's width I cannot just set a fixed size to keep the table within the div. Ultimately I could wrap all of the div content within a table and layout the elements that way, but I was hoping there would be a better, simpler solution by adjusting my css. Thanks!

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
|-margin-|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| (div)   +---------------------------------------------------------+|
|         | (table)                                                 ||
|         |                                                         ||
|         +---------------------------------------------------------+|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What I'm getting:

```
|-margin-|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| (div)   +----------------------------------------------------------|-------+
|         | (table)                                                  |       |
|         |                                                          |       |
|         +----------------------------------------------------------|-------+
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Update:
Thanks for all the suggestions. As I was typing out an even longer winded response the answer dawned on me. I thought that `width:100%` meant "fill but remain within the boundaries of the parent element", not "assume the designated width of the parent element". Since the `margin-left:80px` property set on the table was causing all the trouble I removed it and simply set the div's `padding-left:80px` and that fixed the problem.

@Ace - I really wasn't "asking people to do all the work for me". Since I described exactly what I did I figured the very simple css wasn't necessary, but I suppose it might have been helpful. So here it is, along with the final css that worked:

Original css:

```
.mydiv {
position:relative;
border:1px solid #000000;
}
.myicon {
position:absolute;
left:20;
top:15;
}
.mytable {
border:1px solid #000000; //so I can see it
table-layout:auto;
width:100%;
margin-left:80px;
}
```

Final css:

```
.mydiv {
position:relative;
padding-left:80px;
border:1px solid #000000;
}
.myicon {
position:absolute;
left:20;
top:15;
}
.mytable {
border:1px solid #000000; //so I can see it
table-layout:auto;
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: code ? dont ask people to do all the word 4 you ^^

Comment: It's outside the div because of the left margin **and** the fact that you told it to be the same width as the div. It had no choice.

Comment: p.s. ( mark as answer if there is the one )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed tables's `margin-left:80px` and added `padding-left:80px` to the div container:

```
.mydiv {
position:relative;
padding-left:80px;
border:1px solid #000000;
}
.myicon {
position:absolute;
left:20;
top:15;
}
.mytable {
border:1px solid #000000; //so I can see it
table-layout:auto; 
width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you make the ICON a **CSS background image** in the wrapping DIV, all you need is some margin-left on the table and all will be well.

Comment: Or absolutely-position the image instead of the table.

Comment: You don't need to absolutely-position anything.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
#tableID{
    left:100px; // the margin left
    right:10px;
}
```

it works on divs, but didn't try on table

Comment: so , the same u did with the icon.